# How to get entity id by SKU and ATTRIBUTE ID in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have created an extension that creates product attribute **"Is Old"** after installing extension. Attribute is in drop down form with Yes and No.

Attribute value is saving in **"catalog_product_entity_int"** table.

The main purpose of creating this attribute is that admin can decide if current product is old or not.

Now I want to fetch all those product's entity id that is set to "**YES**" in "**Is Old**" drop down value and by specific SKU.

I have fetched product's entity id by SKU but now I want to fetch entity id by sku and is_old value "Yes" as well.

Here is my code to fetch product entity id by SKU only.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

$select = "Select * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE sku='123'";
$rowArray = $connection->fetchRow($select);
$enitity_id = $rowArray['entity_id'];
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't understand why are you fetching a product id by filtering with **SKU** and **is_old** attribute. Because **SKU** is already an unique value.

I am posting my answer here with two different cases.

**Case 1: Get product Id using sku.**

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getIdBySku('your_sku');
print_r($productId);

?>
```

**Case 2: Get old products using sku.**

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_old',1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('sku1','sku2',.....));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($products->getData());

?>
```

Comment: I need same in Magento 2.1.9 version. Can you please help.

Comment: it works for me,please use "\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();" instead of " Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();"

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calling direct query, my suggestion is to get Magento collection by using  product collection factory class:

**`Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`**

Then filter that collection via `addAttributeTofilter`

```
<?php
namespace [YourClassNameSpace];
class [ClasssName]
{
     protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        ...
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        .....
    }

      public function  getProductCollection(){

         $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
         // Assume tghat yes/no attribute code
         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('Is Old_ATTRIBUTE_CODE',1); //Use 1 for yes value
         /* Filter collection by multiple sk */
          $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('Sku1','sku2'.....,'sku2'));

      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the product id via SKU by using this class:

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product**

```
protected $_productCollection;

public function __construct(
.......
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productCollection,
.......
){
$this->_productCollection = $productCollection;
.....
}   

public function getProductIdBySku() {
        $sku = "your_sku";
        $productId = $this->_productCollection->getIdBySku($sku);
        print_r($productId);
}
```